# docker run and docker run -it do not provide same binary

Tags: python-3.x, docker, nose

I made a docker for my project where I'm using python and the command `nosetests`. My issue is the following :
I want to do a script which run my tests in the docker. So I used the command `docker run --rm pfp nosetests .` in my script but I got the following error : `/src/test/resources/test_in_docker.sh: line 38: nosetests: command not found`

I was curious about that so :

- I went in the docker itself

with `docker run --rm pfp /bin/bash` and did I `whereis nosetests` which returned `nosetests: /usr/local/bin/nosetests`, so everything make sense, nosetests is installed and available. More ever I was able to run my tests.

- I checked it without going inside the container

I did `docker run --rm pfp printenv && echo --- && ls /usr/local/bin | grep -i nose` which returned the following :

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=a0bac6123ed1
TERM=xterm
INSTALL_DIR=/install
WORKSPACE=/workspace
DATA=/data
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
PYTHONPATH=:/workspace/pfp/src/main/python
HOME=/root
---
theano-nose
```

I know that my PYTHONPATH is kind of weird, but my PATH should be fine as there is /usr/local/bin.

But for some reasons that I'm not able to find out the binary nosetests is not available anymore when I'm not going inside the docker to launch my command.

Could someone give me some answer ?

==== EDIT ====
Below the docker file. The folder package is hosted on the machine and contains some instalation script to make the dockerfile more readable.

```
FROM centos:7

# Set the install dir
ENV INSTALL_DIR=/install
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR/package/

# Location of project and data
ENV WORKSPACE=/workspace
RUN mkdir $WORKSPACE
ENV DATA=/data
RUN mkdir $DATA


# Import package to do install
ADD ./package/ $INSTALL_DIR/package/

# Add basic tools
RUN yum install -y vim mlocate

# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for c++
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
# # Install gcc5.5 to get cpp 14 with new ABI
RUN yum -y install make
RUN $INSTALL_DIR/package/centos7/gcc7.4/install.sh -i $INSTALL_DIR/gcc7.4
RUN export PATH=$INSTALL_DIR/gcc7.4/bin:$INSTALL_DIR/gcc7.4/lib:$INSTALL_DIR/gcc7.4/lib64:$INSTALL_DIR/gcc7.4/include:${PATH}&& $INSTALL_DIR/package/centos7/gcc5.5/install.sh
RUN rm -rf $INSTALL_DIR/gcc7.4

# We want to work with cmake3
RUN yum -y install epel-release
RUN yum -y install cmake3
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/cmake3 /usr/bin/cmake

#Install bfm dependencies
RUN $INSTALL_DIR/package/centos7/proj6.2/install.sh
RUN $INSTALL_DIR/package/centos7/gdal3.0/install.sh

# This will install python 3.6
RUN yum -y install python3 python3-devel
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

RUN $INSTALL_DIR/package/centos7/pfp/install.sh

RUN rm -rf $INSTALL_DIR/package/*

# To make source code importable in test
ENV PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$WORKSPACE/pfp/src/main/python

# Command will be launch from this location
WORKDIR $WORKSPACE/pfp/src/main/python/
```

Comment: `docker run --rm pfp /bin/bash -c "nosetests"`

Comment: Can you include your Dockerfile in the question?  I'm suspicious you might have tried to set up something important in shell dotfiles, but typical Docker paths don't actually run them.

Comment: the /bin/bash -c "nosetests" worked, thx